# Sending email from a linked account (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps

I have a script which sends an automated email. I want this to be sent from one of my linked accounts' email addresses rather than my main one, and I had understand that the advanced option 'from' could be used to achieve this... but it is not working. Here is the sending code:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(toEmailAddress, subject, message, {
  htmlBody: htmlMessage,
  name: "Test Name",
  from: "yyy@gmail.com"
});
```

So the message sends, and the name does indeed show up as 'Test Name' but the email is still my main on and not yyy@gmail.com...

I have double checked and this email address is definitely set up in my main account as linked and shows under the 'send email as' section in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the getAliases() method to do this. It's in the reference guide under GmailApp methods.

getAliases()
Gets a list of the emails that are set up as aliases for this account in Gmail.

You can send a message from any of these aliases by using the "from" optional argument.

// Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.

var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();

Logger.log(aliases);

if (aliases.length > 0) {

GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});

} else {

GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');

}